# Nixos unable to modify or chmod nix config - '/etc/nix/nix.conf'

Tags: permissions, nixos, nix

```
[root@nixos:/etc/nix]# sudo chmod 777 /etc/nix/nix.conf
chmod: changing permissions of '/etc/nix/nix.conf': Read-only file system
```

I remember this is some filesystem / Linux kernel utility to change this, I'm not sure what it's called though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This file is managed by Nix - hence it's in the store path - and read only:

```
readlink -f /etc/nix/nix.conf 
/nix/store/9cidrvc5n3fjf9zplxrwiyh0g9nq07bb-nix.conf
```

Instead in order to modify this, you need to set the [`nix.extraOptions`](https://search.nixos.org/options?channel=23.11&show=nix.extraOptions&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=nix.extraOptions) in `configuration.nix` to modify this file.

https://github.com/NixOS/nix/pull/3111

---

Nix config can also be set at `~/.config/nix/nix.conf` though see here for more info: https://nixos.org/manual/nix/unstable/command-ref/conf-file.html

Comment: I'm relatively new to NixOS, and I'm trying to install on MacOS, and I need to edit nix.conf to add some substituters. Where do I find configuration.nix?

Comment: Not sure about MacOS, but I think you can instead set it at ~/.config/nix/nix.conf

Comment: Thanks @chris, I found i could edit /etc/nix/nix.conf using $ sudo vi /etc/nix/nix.conf